# Cannot retrieve name from Users database (mysql) using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display a `"Welcome back, <name>."` to my blog when I log in back. I'm using php to access the database, get the name and last name of the username currently in `$_SESSION['username']`, and then print it back in the index.

So the function to query the database is:

```
 function get_full_name($username){

    $real = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `last` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = `{$username}`");

    $row = mysql_num_rows($query);

    foreach($row as $k => $v)
    {
        $real[$k] = $v;
    }

       return $real;
  }
```

Then the part of the html where it calls the function above:

```
<div id="menu">
    <?php 
            $temp = $_SESSION['username'];
            $real[] = get_full_name($temp);
            if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
            {
                echo '<br />'.'Welcome back, '. $real['name'] . '.';
            }
    ?>
    </div>
```

The output of the above codes is:

```
 Welcome back, .
```

var_dump($real) gives:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }
```

var_dump($real) after changing to mysql_fectch_assoc:

```
array(0) { }
```

- Fixed: The error was not using the single quotes ' {$username} '

By changing them, it worked like a charm, cheers to all!

Comment: try var_dump($real) to see what indexes it has. I seem to remember mysql_num_rows being the wrong function if you want an associative array back.

Comment: Go ahead and accept incarnate's answer--it's the right one.

Comment: I've done what the answer says but, still its not working.

Comment: Have you done var_dump after using mysql_fetch_assoc? Good way to confirm it's working and to see what you're actually getting back from your indexes.

Comment: Just added the new var_dump, cheers!

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Christian, are you sure there's a record in the database for your username?

Also, please post your updated code with mysql_fetch_assoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_full_name()` function should be like this:

```
function get_full_name($username) {
   $real  = array();
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `last` 
                         FROM `users` 
                         WHERE `user` = '{$username}'");
   if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
     $real = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
   }

   return $real;
}
```

Notes:

- Use single quotes for the variable: `'{$username}'` instead of `` `{$username}` ``
- Use `mysql_num_rows()` for checking if the result is not empty.
- Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` for retrieving the row.

Calling the function:

```
$temp = $_SESSION['username'];
$real = get_full_name($temp);
if (isset($temp) && count($real)) {
   echo '<br />Welcome back, '. $real['name'] . '.';
}
```

Notes:

- Use `$real` instead of `$real[]`.
- Check if `$real` empty with `count()`.

Answer (score 2):

Curiously you are using `mysql_num_rows` to get the results of your query. This will only return the number of rows. You'll be better off using [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to get the associative array of results.

You also need to change your backticks to single quotes around `{$username}` in the query.

Something like:

```php
function get_full_name($username){

    $real = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `last` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '{$username}'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    foreach($row as $k => $v)
    {
        $real[$k] = $v;
    }

    return $real;
}
```

Comment: Somehow this is not working, still showing me no printed name, but i didnt understand why before it wouldnt work at all, this seems logical but still its not working for me =/, must be doing something else wrng?

Comment: See also Nick's solution, you need to remove the [] from 
$real[] = get_full_name($temp);
bsdnoobz has an even more comprehensive writeup!

Comment: Yes, it worked!! So the error was just the ` {$username} ` quotes instead of '{$username}' ! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);`

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I see.

1) You are using `mysql_num_rows`, not fetching the array of data from the database.

```
function get_full_name($username){

    $real = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `last` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = `{$username}`");

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    foreach($row as $k => $v)
    {
        $real[$k] = $v;
    }

    return $real;
}
```

2) Looks like `$real` is a multi-dimention array in your code. Try this instead:

```
<div id="menu">
    <?php 
            $temp = $_SESSION['username'];
            $real = get_full_name($temp);
            if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
            {
                echo '<br />'.'Welcome back, '. $real['name'] . '.';
            }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Notice I've removed the `[]` at the end of `$real`.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_query() to get the result of running the query, then use mysql_fetch_assoc() to get individual rows.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   var_dump($row);
}
```

Note that mysql_num_rows($result) will return the number of rows in a given result.